# Right way to handle Firebase DatabaseReference updateChildren OnCompletionListener on Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase database and want that offline persistence should also work. I have seen that when calling `DatabaseReference.updateChildren` in offline mode, value listener callbacks are triggered immediately, while the `OnCompletionListener` triggers only when the network is back. Is that the correct understanding? If so, what are clients expected to do in case of success or failure in OnCompletionListener.

Specifically -

1. If the OnCompletionListener gets a failure, is the change rolled back locally and all value-listener-callbacks fired with the rolled back value?
2. In what scenarios could the OnCompletionListener return failure? Is there a case which needs to be retried?
3. What would be a typical usecase to listen to OnCompletionListener's success instead of callback in ValueChangeListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that the correct understanding?

Yes, it is.

When there is a loss of network connectivity (there is no network connection on user device), neither `onComplete()` nor `onFailure()` are triggered. This behavior makes sense, since the task is only considered completed when the data has been committed (or rejected) on the Firebase server.

1. There is no rolled back because when data is updated, it is first written to the local version of the database, obviously when the persistence is enabled using the following line of code:

   ```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
   ```
2. When Firebase servers reject the update due the `insufficient permissions` caused by Firebase Security rules.
3. This is the typical usecase, to listen to OnCompletionListener's success.

Comment: 1. But there won't be any rules or permission check locally (when no network), other listeners will see the updated value which will later be rejected by the server. So the local commit would need a rollback, or am I missing something? 
3. So, it is only to handle failures? Successful states would already have been visible to other listeners.

Comment: 1. This can happen only if you go offline, change online the security rules and then came back only. Yes, in this case, Firebase servers will reject the update operation. All the operations with insufficient permissions will not take place. 3. Yes

Comment: Is there everything alright?
Can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Just waiting to see if anyone else has something to add. Will accept the answer in a day or two :)

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Cheers!